# Rails: Download by Mechanize custom filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, mechanize

Now i'm trying to download an random-avatar for users while registering.
So i get Mechanize and do this after research.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
def new
    super
end
def create
    agent = Mechanize.new
    agent.pluggable_parser.default = Mechanize::Download
    f = agent.get('http://avatar.3sd.me/100')
    f.save('public/images/avatar/it_should_be_user_id.png')
    super
end
def update
    super
end
end
```

But i cannot figure out how to save the file in the specific name according to the user id, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you call super first in the `create` method, so the default setup of the devise controller happens before your code gets executed.

Inside the `RegistrationsController` class you can access the current user with the variable/method `resource` (instead of something like `current_user`). So your code would look like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def new
        super
    end
    def create
        super
        agent = Mechanize.new
        agent.pluggable_parser.default = Mechanize::Download
        f = agent.get('http://avatar.3sd.me/100')
        f.save("public/images/avatar/#{resource.id}.png")
    end
    def update
        super
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm glad it does. Would you mind accepting this answer as the best one then?